# Ender 3 Pro extruder drive rocking back and forth

Tags: creality-ender-3, extrusion, wiring, extruder-driver

I've been running this Ender 3 Pro for quite some time with no problem up until recently. The issue was the printer refused to extrude filament (the extruder stepper seems to be rocking back and forth) so I went through a few things to try and fix the problem:

- I leveled the bed properly
- I printed at higher temperatures (215 °C for PLA which is the only filament I run in this printer)
- I cleaned the nozzle and I actually replaced the nozzle with a new 0.4 mm nozzle
  (same size as before)
- I replaced my Bowden tube with a newer one (unbranded) and even replaced the tube fittings for the extruder assembly and the heat sink.

I saw somewhere that maybe the wiring to the extruder gear is frayed but I inspected the extruder side of the connector and everything looks fine. I would open up the box and everything but I want to see if anyone has a solution before opening up the circuit  box.

Comment: The question title suggests it is trying to move, but jitters, correct? Be sure that the extrusion speed doesn't exceed the maximum speed, steppers rock back and forth if a too high of a speed is commanded.

Comment: My extrusion speed is 60 mm/s which is pretty standard from everything that I've seen. This speed works fine on all my other Ender 3 Pro's so I don't think that is the issue but I will slow down the speed and test just in case.

Comment: No need to lower it, just establishing that it did not accidentally was too high of a speed!

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? My Ender 3 Pro after 3 months running flawless just started this. I have swapped my board and i think it is a cable just curious if that was your problem.

Comment: @RobDavis Hey so it turns out, the motor was bad. I replace the motor with another one off of a good printer and it turns no problem. Just had to get another motor online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like one end or the other in your stepper cable is not seated correctly or has shaken loose there are 4 wires if even one doesn't make proper contact you will get a shaking back and forth almost like a hard vibration. I always take a cable from one of the other steppers plug into this one move the motor with good stepper wire 10-20 mm see what motor does if it is okay then you know it is a cable issue if not, it could be a bad board or stepper.

Comment: ALright, I will try this out and let you know if the problem is with the cable or not.

Comment: The cable is indeed the problem as the motor moves filament through no problem so I will check the extruder cable.