# Extruder doing the shimmy, How can I fix?

Tags: extruder, stepper, monoprice-maker-select, extruder-driver, nema-17

**Printer:** Monoprice Maker Select V2 3D Printer

**Problem:** Extruder not working

**History:** My extruder was clogged and I didn't realize it at first and I opened the extruder and pulled out the stuck piece but later I realized it still was not working. When I put pressure on it the motor rotates and the filament comes out but does not work by it self.

**Try 1:** Thought something was wrong with the gears so I reseated them, Didn't work.

**Try 2**: Thought the extruder motor broke, so I replace the NEMA 17 motor, Didn't work.

**Try 3:** Plugged the motor into the x-axis plug the motor works as shown here - 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/kY4okR4oqkYSyzhN8

This is how the motor behaves when pluged into the [original] extruder plug-
https://photos.app.goo.gl/QPo7RNeB6AFi6KsM6

Any help is appreciated, Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Did you try a different cable on extruder replacing the current one?

Comment: Have you looked into [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/ender-3-pro-extruder-drive-rocking-back-and-forth)?

Comment: @0scar Thank you for your reply, I checked the cable with my multimeter all the wires are working as intended. My only thinking is the the board some how is damaged. Should I order a new board?

Comment: I also tried increasing the voltage too the nema motor as suggested in the other thread that also didnt fix the issue

Comment: My second guess was also a fried board...

Answer (score 2):

It was the stepper driver, Replacing the motherboard fixed the issue.

Comment: Many thanks for answering your own question! Glad to see you got it fixed, happy printing!